# Ruby - How to remove duplicates in array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of hashes within an array of hashes. I'd like to remove duplicates based on the values of the inner arrays.

```
topics = [{"defense"=>
   [{:id=>30,
     :source=>"Hacker News",
     :title=>
      "China-based campaign breached satellite, defense companies: Symantec",
     :link=>
      "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-china-usa-cyber/china-based-campaign-breached-satellite-defense-companies-symantec-idUSKBN1JF2X0"}]},
 {"companies"=>
   [{:id=>30,
     :source=>"Hacker News",
     :title=>
      "China-based campaign breached satellite, defense companies: Symantec",
     :link=>
      "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-china-usa-cyber/china-based-campaign-breached-satellite-defense-companies-symantec-idUSKBN1JF2X0"}]},
 {"Symantec"=>
   [{:id=>30,
     :source=>"Hacker News",
     :title=>
      "China-based campaign breached satellite, defense companies: Symantec",
     :link=>
      "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-china-usa-cyber/china-based-campaign-breached-satellite-defense-companies-symantec-idUSKBN1JF2X0"}]}]

topics.uniq { |phrase, post| post }
puts topics
```

You can see above that the phrases `defense`, `companies`, and `Symantec` each contain identical arrays. How can I keep only the first hash that contains one of the identical arrays?

Expected output:

```
{"defense"=>
  [{:id=>30,
    :source=>"Hacker News",
    :title=>
     "China-based campaign breached satellite, defense companies: Symantec",
    :link=>
     "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-china-usa-cyber/china-based-campaign-breached-satellite-defense-companies-symantec-idUSKBN1JF2X0"}]}
```

Note: in the above example each inner array of "phrases" only contains one hash, but in the application it could contain several posts.

Comment: Handling the data would probably be easier if you would remove those extra arrays, i.e. `topics = {"defense" => { id: 30, ... }, "companies" => { id: 30, ...}}`. Just saying ;-)

Comment: @stefan is there a way I can do that and maintain the ability for each phrase to contain multiple posts? In the example above, I'm only showing one article linked to the phrase "defense", but in reality there could be multiple posts under that phrase.

Comment: Then you could have `{"defense" => [{...}, {...}], "companies" => [...] }`, but there's no need to wrap each phrase-posts pair in a separate hash. It seems like `topics` should be a single hash with `topics.keys` returning `["defense", "companies", "Symantec"]`

Comment: Maybe you could adapt your example a little bit more to the actual values, i.e. add some posts that are common to all phrases and others that are unique. Then show your expected result. And maybe you can reduce the amount of example data, e.g. just have `:id` and a short `:title`.

Comment: What happens if the topic value has more than 1 item? Is the `Array` supposed to be unique or the resulting `Hash` should have only 1 occurrence of any of the values? right now this would work for when the full `Array` is considered the value and the requirement for uniqueness. `topics.map(&:values).uniq.map {|v| topics.find {|h| h.values == v } }`. However the conversion to a `Hash` could be obtained by chaining `reduce(&:merge)` to the end but converting this `Array` to a `Hash` seems counter productive if a key could occur more than 1 time in topics with different values

Answer (score 3):

`topics.invert.invert` will reduce the hash to a single (arbitrarily-chosen) key for each unique value.

Comment: Unfortunately, `topics` is an array and the values are spread across different hashes.

Comment: Ah.. `topics.inject(:merge).invert.invert`? :/

Comment: It will not be arbitrary it will be last result wins which in this case would be `"Symantec"` not `"defense"` as the question suggests the result should be

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you get only the array:

```
topics.map { |topic| topic.values }.uniq.flatten
```

It returns just:

```
# => [{:id=>30, :source=>"Hacker News", :title=>"China-based campaign breached satellite, defense companies: Symantec", :link=>"https://www.reuters.com/article/us-china-usa-cyber/china-based-campaign-breached-satellite-defense-companies-symantec-idUSKBN1JF2X0"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
topics = [
  { "defense"   => [{ id: 30, source: "Hacker", title: "China", link: "F2X0"}] },
  { "companies" => [{ id: 30, source: "Hacker", title: "China", link: "F2X0"}] },
  { "Symantec"  => [{ id: 30, source: "Hacker", title: "China", link: "F2X0"}] }
]

topics.uniq { |h| h.values }
  #=> [{"defense"=>[{:id=>30, :source=>"Hacker", :title=>"China", :link=>"F2X0"}]}]
```

See [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) for the case when `uniq` employs a block. Note the sentence, "`self` is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept."